# How to make a word list have all lowercase letters

Tags: python, word-list

I created a hangman game but when I enter the correct letter if it is not the correct uppercase/lowercase then it counts it wrong. I don't know how to convert my word list in only lowercase letters. My word list is on another file that I imported. Below is the code.

`

```
import random
import time
from words import word_list

# Initial Steps to invite in the game:
print("\nWelcome to Hangman!\n")
name = input("Enter Your name: ")
print("Hello " + name + "! Good Luck!")
time.sleep(2)
print("The Game is About to Start!\n Let's Play Hangman!")
time.sleep(3)


# The parameters we require to execute the game:
def main():
    global count
    global display
    global word
    global already_guessed
    global length
    global play_game
    words_to_guess = (word_list)
    word = random.choice(words_to_guess)
    length = len(word)
    count = 0
    display = '_' * length
    already_guessed = []
    play_game = ""

# A loop to re-execute the game when the first round ends:

def play_loop():
    global play_game
    play_game = input("Do You want to play again? y = yes, n = no \n")
    while play_game not in ["y", "n","Y","N"]:
        play_game = input("Do You want to play again? y = yes, n = no \n")
    if play_game == "y":
        main()
    elif play_game == "n":
        print("Thanks For Playing! We expect you back again!")
        exit()

# Initializing all the conditions required for the game:
def hangman():
    global count
    global display
    global word
    global already_guessed
    global play_game
    limit = 9
    guess = input("This is the Hangman Word: " + display + " Enter your guess: \n")
    guess = guess.strip()
    if len(guess.strip()) == 0 or len(guess.strip()) >= 2 or guess <= "9":
        print("Invalid Input, Try a letter\n")
        hangman()


    elif guess in word:
        already_guessed.extend([guess])
        index = word.find(guess)
        word = word[:index] + "_" + word[index + 1:]
        display = display[:index] + guess + display[index + 1:]
        print(display + "\n")

    elif guess in already_guessed:
        print("Try another letter.\n")

    else:
        count += 1

        if count == 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 2:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 3:
           time.sleep(1)
           print("   _____ \n"
                 "  |     | \n"
                 "  |     |\n"
                 "  |     | \n"
                 "  |      \n"
                 "  |      \n"
                 "  |      \n"
                 "__|__\n")
           print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " guesses remaining\n")

        elif count == 4:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     O \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " last guess remaining\n")

        elif count == 5:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     O \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " last guess remaining\n")

        elif count == 6:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     O \n"
                  "  |    /| \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " last guess remaining\n")

        elif count == 7:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     O \n"
                  "  |    /|\ \n"
                  "  |      \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " last guess remaining\n")

        elif count == 8:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     O \n"
                  "  |    /|\ \n"
                  "  |    /  \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. " + str(limit - count) + " last guess remaining\n")

        elif count == 9:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("   _____ \n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     |\n"
                  "  |     | \n"
                  "  |     O \n"
                  "  |    /|\ \n"
                  "  |    / \ \n"
                  "__|__\n")
            print("Wrong guess. You are hanged!!!\n")
            print("The word was:",already_guessed,word)
            play_loop()

    if word == '_' * length:
        print("Congrats! You have guessed the word correctly!")
        play_loop()

    elif count != limit:
        hangman()


main()


hangman()
```

`

I wanted the letter to be counted right regardless if it is inputted as uppercase or lowercase. What resulted was it being counted as an incorrect guess even though the letter was correct.

Constructive Feedback Wanted!

Comment: convert word list into lowercase:   `myList = [i.lower() for i in myList]`

Comment: `guess = input("...").lower()`. You can also convert the word list to lower like this `list(map(str.lower, word_list))`

Comment: Start working on breaking yourself of the habit of declaring everything `global`.  Ideally you don't use `global` *at all* (you should use function args and return values to pass information between functions), but at the very least if you're going to use `global` you should think about what exactly it's doing and why you need it in a particular place.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A bit off-topic, but it seems like you forgot to strip guess exactly 11 times in a row. You only stripped it 4 times in a row. However, 3 of them were stripping a guess that's already been stripped so, that probably counts as 7.